# Is there a way to show the plugged in removable drives on the {unity} desktop?

Tags: unity, 13.04, customization

Is there a way to display drive icons, like in GNOME 2.x and Cinnamon on the Unity desktop?

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using? I think displaying the mounted volumes in the desktop is the default, at least on 12.04

Comment: 13.04 *I hate comments and their character minimums

Comment: Thats why you should edit your question to provide additional information :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install and try the Unity Tweak Tool, it has lots of options to customize your desktop.

Go into Unity-Tweak-Tool and under System>Desktop Icons, change which ones you want to enable.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute in a terminal

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop volumes-visible true
```

mounted volumes should now appear on the desktop.